# Output in desired format

Tags: php

```
$values = array();
while($root = mysql_fetch_array($res)){

$root["prefix"] = $this->get_prefix($root['position']);
}
return $values;
```

I am getting the output as >>,position name

But I want... >>position name... is it possible to remove the comma.

Comment: the code that you posted has absolutely nothing to do with the output you're getting.

Comment: I agree, unless what you call 'output' is $root["prefix"]

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't knowing the original code...

```
$root["prefix"] = preg_replace('/^>>,/','>>', $this->get_prefix($root['position']));
```

Comment: That doesn't help at all.  Don't use a RegEX just because you can - in this case it looks like the OP has not actually posted all the code; there is probably some much simpler fix for this problem.